# Flutter create a transsission from a GridView element to Header

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for an animation from a GridView Selection to a new Page.

Here is the transmission I like to have:

[image: 1]
[image]

But I don't know how to make this. I could use a AnimatedContainer for each GridViewItem, but this would not help to "break out" from the Grid during the animation.

Should I use a Stack and a Positioned AnimatedContainer? What is the best attempt here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Hero Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations). In Simple, you'll have to wrap the grid element with the hero widget and pass the tag within the screen.

A Code example is available in the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html#widgets.Hero.1).